# sorting kmeans cluster labels according to the input values

Tags: r, sorting, cluster-analysis

I have a range of values and I want to identify the cluster with the lowest values using kmeans. However the cluster labels seem to be sorted in a different way then I was looking for.

```
test <- c(1,4,5,12,17,18,33,34)
cl <- kmeans(test, centers = 3, nstart =10)
cl$cluster
[1] 2 2 2 1 1 1 3 3
# whereas I would have expected to get
[1] 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3
```

How can I sort the output from kmeans in the way that I want?

Comment: `cl$clusters` gives me `NULL`. It's cluster not clusters.

Comment: You can use `sort` on `cl$cluster`

Comment: cluster labels are not ordinal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no guarantee that low numbers will be grouped with other low numbers and you do not say precisely how you want the clusters ordered. Here is one way; you can order the clusters by the lowest point index in the cluster.  That will produce the result that you asked for on this test data.

```
MT = aggregate(test, list(cl$cluster), min)
MT$Group.1[order(MT$x)[cl$cluster]]
[1] 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3
```

If you want to propagate this change to `cl` you can just make the assignement

```
cl$cluster = MT$Group.1[order(MT$x)[cl$cluster]]
```